# How can i get the time in another country or specific location in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, time, geolocation

How can I get the time in another country or a specific location in flutter? Can't find a free API that does it with lat and long. What is the easiest way to get the time or UTC offset in another country using coordinates.

Comment: Hello, please checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates/16086964 it has been validated by the community.

Comment: You can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone)

Comment: even you can use this API http://worldtimeapi.org/